# Cross Sub Domain Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to carry my cookie across sub domains, but I can't seem to get it to carry. I want the domain to be .apus.edu in the cookie, but the cookie is either catalog.apus.edu, amu.apus.edu or apu.apus.edu

Here's my starting page. you'll be assigned a default cookie
http://catalog.apus.edu/sitecat/cookie.htm

When you click on AMU, you'll be assigned AMU Cookie, etc.

When you reach the control page, you should have either AMU or APU otherwise I assign you default.

I just really want the domain to be .apus.edu instead of each of the sub domains.

```
function Set_Cookie( name, value, expires, path, domain, secure ) {
    // set time, it's in milliseconds
    var today = new Date();
    today.setTime( today.getTime() );

    /*
    if the expires variable is set, make the correct
    expires time, the current script below will set
    it for x number of days, to make it for hours,
    delete * 24, for minutes, delete * 60 * 24
    */
    if ( expires ) { expires = expires * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; }
    var expires_date = new Date( today.getTime() + (expires) );

    document.cookie = name + "=" +escape( value ) +
    ( ( expires ) ? ";expires=" + expires_date.toGMTString() : "" ) +
    ( ( path ) ? ";path=" + path : "" ) +
    ( ( domain ) ? ";domain=" + domain : "" ) +
    ( ( secure ) ? ";secure" : "" );
}

function Get_Cookie( check_name ) {
    // first we'll split this cookie up into name/value pairs
    // note: document.cookie only returns name=value, not the other components
    var a_all_cookies = document.cookie.split( ';' );
    var a_temp_cookie = '';
    var cookie_name = '';
    var cookie_value = '';
    var b_cookie_found = false; // set boolean t/f default f

    for ( i = 0; i < a_all_cookies.length; i++ ) {
        // now we'll split apart each name=value pair
        a_temp_cookie = a_all_cookies[i].split( '=' );

        // and trim left/right whitespace while we're at it
        cookie_name = a_temp_cookie[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

        // if the extracted name matches passed check_name
        if ( cookie_name == check_name ) {
            b_cookie_found = true;
            // we need to handle case where cookie has no value but exists (no = sign, that is):
            if ( a_temp_cookie.length > 1 ) {
                cookie_value = unescape( a_temp_cookie[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') );
            }
            // note that in cases where cookie is initialized but no value, null is returned
            return cookie_value;
            break;
        }
        a_temp_cookie = null;
        cookie_name = '';
    }
    if ( !b_cookie_found ) {
        return null;
    }
}

// this deletes the cookie when called
function Delete_Cookie( name, path, domain ) {
    if ( Get_Cookie( name ) ) document.cookie = name + "=" +
    ( ( path ) ? ";path=" + path : "") +
    ( ( domain ) ? ";domain=" + domain : "" ) +
    ";expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT";
}

var CookieNameDefault = 'Default Cookie';
var CookieValueDefault = 'Default Cookie';

var CookieNameAMU = 'AMU Cookie';
var CookieValueAMU = 'AMU Cookie';

var CookieNameAPU = 'APU Cookie';
var CookieValueAPU = 'APU Cookie';

var cAMU = Get_Cookie(CookieNameAMU); 
var cAPU = Get_Cookie(CookieNameAPU); 

if (window.location.href.indexOf("www.amu.apus.edu/_test/sitecat/cookie.htm") >= 0) { //delete APU & Default cookie and set AMU cookie
    Delete_Cookie(CookieNameAPU, '/', '');
    Delete_Cookie(CookieNameDefault, '/', '');
    Set_Cookie(CookieNameAMU, CookieValueAMU, '', '/', '', '');
    alert(CookieNameAMU);
}

if (window.location.href.indexOf("www.apu.apus.edu/_test/sitecat/cookie.htm") >= 0) { //delete AMU & Default cookie and set APU cookie
    Delete_Cookie(CookieNameAMU, '/', '');
    Delete_Cookie(CookieNameDefault, '/', '');
    Set_Cookie(CookieNameAPU, CookieValueAPU, '', '/', '', '');
    alert(CookieNameAPU);
}

if (cAMU || cAPU) { 
    // check if you have any of these two cookies if so then do nothing
}
else { // if you don't have any cookie then lets give you the default cookie
    Set_Cookie( CookieNameDefault, CookieValueDefault, '', '/', '', '' ); 
    alert(CookieNameDefault);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm not 100% sure what is going on in that huge block of code. However if you set your cookies domain to `.apus.edu` then it will be available to `*.apus.edu`.

I.E. Where you have:

```
Set_Cookie(CookieNameAMU, CookieValueAMU, '', '/', '', '');
```

Should be

```
Set_Cookie(CookieNameAMU, CookieValueAMU, '', '/', '.apus.edu', '');
```

Comment: That did the trick! I am very grateful. May I ask also I noticed my cookie resets itself back to my default cookie when I close my browser. I thought the point of the cookie was until you delete cookies (or they expire) the cookie would be persistent when you return back to the site?

Comment: @Evan The cookie should be persistent. Use the resource manger in chrome debugging tools to check cookies.

Comment: Now it's persistent i specified it not expire until a whole year. It was expiring on browser close since there was no date.

Set_Cookie( CookieNameAMU, CookieValueAMU, '365', '/', '.apus.edu', ''); Thanks again for the big help. I have a full tracking system in place now.

Answer (score 1):

You should indicate the higher domain who can read this cookie
If you set catalog.apus.edu , it can be accessed by subdomain.catalog.apus.edu , but not by apus.edu nor other.apus.edu

so, you must set the domain as apus.edu , so can be accessed by apus.edu , www.apus.edu, anysubdomain.apus.edu,...

```
Set_Cookie(CookieNameAMU, CookieValueAMU, '', '/', 'apus.edu' , '');
```